# Passing through data to Vue component?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, vue.js

I'm currently working with Vue, and we have a main Vue instance with multiple components in the `.vue` format. However, when we use Socket.IO we have to create the Socket.IO instance in the component. Is there a way to instantiate Socket.IO in our main Vue instance and pass it through to the components?

Answer (score 3):

You could instantiate it in the parent, then pass it to the children via `$broadcast` and `$on` :

```
new Vue({
     ...
     data: {
          sock: {}
     },
     compiled: function(){
          this.sock = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');
          this.$broadcast('socketReady',this.sock);
     }
     ...
});

var someChild = new Vue({
     ...
     data: {
          sock: {}
     } 
     compiled: function(){
          this.$on('socketReady', function(sock){
               this.sock = sock;
               socket.on(
                    "test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName",
                    function(message){
                         //do something with message
                    }
               );
          });
     }
     ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using props to pass the Socket.IO IP through into the instance, do you know if I can add the prop into my component and then use it in the main Vue object?

Comment: does each component needs a socket instance with a different IP?

Answer (score 1):

This article shows one method of including js libraries with Vue: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

Essentially, you could do something like this:

```
var socket = // create socket here
Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$socket', { value: socket })
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
new Vue({
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$socket);
  }
})
```

However, if you are using a module bundler like Webpack, I would suggest just exporting the socket instance from a file and importing it in whatever components need it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to pass data to components would be through properties.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props

The cool thing with Vue is that you can two-way bind these props!

Here's an example of how it might look like in your case.

```
new Vue({

     data: {
          connected: false
     },

     ready: {
         createConnection.then(function () {
             connected = true;
         });
     }

});
```

Template:

```
<component :connected="connected"></component>
```

Component:

```
Vue.component('component', {
    props: {
        connected: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
            twoWay: true
        }
    }
});
```

You can use the same technique to pass a connection object and two-way bind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it globally in the main.js or whatever you are using to instantiate vue and it will be available for use in your components. I have done this with Jquery (modularly) on many occasions.